# Getting a UILabel's Text to Change when Checking for Invalid Characters

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I'm having trouble getting the `UILabel`'s text to change when an invalid character is being used in a username. Currently, the rest of the code works fine - including the animation and vibration.

**Here's my code:**

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

    let forbiddenUsernameCharacters = [".", " ", "#", "$", "[", "}", "]", "{", "(", "}"]

    guard let username = self.usernameTextField.text else { return }

    if textField == usernameTextField  && self.usernameTextField.text != "" {

        if !forbiddenUsernameCharacters.contains(where: username.contains) {
            print("Done")
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {

                //Handle Global
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.checkForUserName(requestedUsername: self.usernameTextField.text!.lowercased())
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.errorLabel.text = "Invalid Characters"
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            print("Invalid Characters")
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (1352)


            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
            animation.duration = 0.07
            animation.repeatCount = 4
            animation.autoreverses = true
            animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.usernameTextField.center.x - 10, y: self.usernameTextField.center.y))
            animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: self.usernameTextField.center.x + 10, y: self.usernameTextField.center.y))

            self.usernameTextField.layer.add(animation, forKey: "position")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well for one thing, you're not updating the `UITextField.text` value if you've found an invalid character.

Comment: I have a label displaying the errors. The usernameTextField will stay the same. Just shakes when error occurs. Have trouble getting the label to display the error.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of almost all occurrences of `self.`, your first `if` condition can just be combined into your `guard`, and you can check if a `String` is empty by using the built-in `.isEmpty` value.